# AWS: How to transfer files from ec2 instance (Windows Server) to S3 daily?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Can someone explain me whats the best way to **transfer data from a harddrive on an EC2 Instance** (running Windows Server 2012) to an S3 Bucket for the same AWS Account **on a daily basis?**

Backround idea to this:
I'm generating a .csv file for one of our Business partners daily at 11:00 am and I want to deliver it to S3 (he has access to our S3 Bucket). 
After that he can pull it out of S3 manually or automatically whenever he wants.

Hope you can help me, I only found manually solutions with the CLI, but no automated way for daily transfers.

**Best Regards**

Comment: Why transfer the file on a daily basis? Whatever process that is generating the file could upload it to S3 _as soon as the file is produced_, rather than waiting for an arbitrary time.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention that - the file is generated by an external software and there is now way to get into this process programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly mount S3 buckets as mounted drives on your EC2 instances. This way you don't even need some sort of triggers/daily task scheduler along with third party service as objects would be directly available in the S3 bucket.

For Linux typically you would use Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE). Take a look at this repo if you need it for Linux: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.

Regarding Windows, there is this tool:
https://tntdrive.com/mount-amazon-s3-bucket.aspx

If these tools don't suit you or if you don't want to mount directly the s3 bucket, here is another option: Whatever you can do with the CLI you should be able to do with the SDK. Therefore if you are able to code in one of the various language AWS Lambda proposes - *C#/Java/Go/Powershell/Python/Node.js/Ruby* - you could automate that using a Lambda function along with a daily task scheduler triggering at 11a.m.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a gem! Didn't know this was possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a small application that uploads your file to an S3 bucket (there are a some example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadInSingleOp.html)). Then use Task Scheduler to execute your application on a regular basis.